# Better way to check for empty function args

Tags: php, function, methods, is-empty

Pretty much all my class methods start the same way, by checking to see if the arguments passed are empty or not (variations for where I am expecting bools and int-0's)

Is there a less repetitive way of checking the values?

```
public function updateproduct($product, $storeid) {
    if ( empty($product) || empty($storeid) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // do stuff

}
```

Comment: Well i guess two options would be to either define your input as an array and then write a function which checks each of the values inside this array, or use `func_get_args()` to get all function parameters. I am not sure if there really is a more practical approach.

Comment: Yeah I cant think of another way to do it, havent looked into any of PHP's magic stuff though..

Comment: You could use type hinting when you require an integer, float, array, etc.  Beyond that, is there a big reason why you'd be passing invalid values to your functions?  Seems like the problem is mostly how you're using the function.

Comment: Rather than checking that you arguments are one or more of the infinite things that they should not be, why not check that you arguments are one of the few things that they *should* be?

Comment: Yeah typing brings exceptions up though, trying to avoid that.
Mainly just for good coding practice, who knows what people behind me will be throwing at the methods when im not looking :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `func_num_args` to iterate over an array of arg values returned by `func_get_args` is one way to accomplish what you are after

```
function foo($numargs, $arg_list) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        if (empty($arg_list[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function bar($arg1, $arg2) {
    if (!foo(func_num_args(), func_get_args())) {
        //...
    }
}

bar('baz', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function tests to see if any of the arguments passed to it are empty. The upside is the simplicity. The downside is that it does not short-circuit if an empty value is found.

I imagine if you were to notice the impact of it not short-circuiting, you are sending too many params to your function.

```
function anyEmpty(...$args){
  return array_filter($args) !== $args;
}
```

Then our usage in updateProduct function:

```
function updateProduct($product, $storeId){
  if (anyEmpty($product, $storeId)) {
    return False;
  }
  //do your stuff
  return True;
}
```

Or alternatively, if you would prefer to specify the params dynamically:

```
  if (anyEmpty(...func_get_args())) {
    return False;
  }
```

Comment: Hm... I am bit puzzled, comparing elements of array_filter()` to array that you are passing to it? Isn't `array_filter()` returning each element of an array?

Comment: `array_filter()` returns a filtered array. If you don't provide a function to it, then it will filter out False values. If the filtered array doesn't match the original array, we know there was a false - or empty - value.